# How can I insert the last Id into the child table :

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert into two tables the mother table and the child table : but the mother table gets the data  and the child table does not : I get the error 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`portfolio`.`players`, CONSTRAINT `players_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
 And bellow is my code :

```
$query="INSERT INTO users(email,date)
VALUES('$email','$date')";
$user_result = mysql_query($query); 
/*last inserted Id */
$id_last = ("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$res = mysql_query($id_last);
$last_id = mysql_fetch_array($res);
/*last inserted Id  ends*/
/*insert query */
$sql="INSERT INTO 
players(name, surname, position, contact_number, email, username, password, date, user_id)
VALUES('$name ','$surname','$position','$contact_number','$email','$username','$password', '$date', '$last_id')";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die (mysql_error()); 
/*if something goes wrong then tell the user*/ 
if($result){
echo "Player Successfully added</br>";

}
else {
echo "We are sorry no player inserted ";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$last_id = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

`mysql_fetch_array` returns array, to get actual id you should use `$last_id[0]`. Also there is function for that: [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). While looking on linked manual page, please pay attention to big red frame, and continue developing with either mysqli or PDO.

Comment: ok but how can I use it because I want the lastid inserted into the user table . can integrate your codes in mine ?

Comment: I used it in pdo but now this requirement it has to my in old mysql_functions thanks